# Resize Android WebView and make it working with "read more" button

Tags: android, webview, resize

The onPageFinished and postVisualStateCallback() both can not guaranty that you can get the height of html content.

This code is from out project to solve using WebView to display HTML content in APP. we will set up a initial size to WebView if content is too long, then user can click "read more" button to expand the WebView to fit the content.

Here is the sample code to share:

--Using NestedScrollView as the parent layout can make WebView change the size according to the content.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
     android:id="@+id/webViewContainer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp">
       <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

--disable NestedScrollView scrolling programmatically

```
webViewContainer.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

--define a GlobalLayoutListener to setup webview size

```
private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener webViewListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int contentHeight = webView.getHeight();
            if(contentHeight==0) return;
            if (contentHeight > UiUtil.dpToPx(150)) {
                 contentHeight = UiUtil.dpToPx(150);
                 readMoreBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                 readMoreBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = webViewContainer.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height =  contentHeight;
            webViewContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            webView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(webViewListener );
        }
    };
```

-- load data and add GlobalLayoutListener

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl,htmlString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8",null);
webView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(VebViewListener);
webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(vebViewListener);
```

-- expand the webViewContainer to see more content

```
readMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
   int contentHeight = webView.getHeight();
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = webViewContainer.getLayoutParams();
   layoutParams.height =  contentHeight;
   webViewContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
   readMoreBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
});
```

This is working well.
Note: The onPageFinished and postVisualStateCallback() both can not guaranty that you can get the height of html content.